# Invoking a method in anonymous (inner) classes

Tags: java, class, interface, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
 interface Example{
   void methodExample();
 }
 class Y{
  void do(Example x) { }
}

class X{
   void methodX() {
     Y y = new Y();
     y.do(new Example() {
       public void methodExample() {
         System.out.println("methodExample");
       } 
     });
   } 
 }
```

I want to create a main class and call `methodExample`. How would I do that?

Comment: Unrelated, but noteworthy: ```do``` is not a valid identifier, because it is also a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your class implements `Example` interface, and because `void methodExample()` is present on that interface, all you need to do is to reference the object by its interface, and call its method:

```
class Y{
    public void doIt(Example x) {
        x.methodExample();
    }
}
```

The above works, because objects of all classes implementing `Example`, including all anonymous implementations, are known at compile time to implement `methodExample()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to class `Y` then, the only way to do is to override `doIt()` itself first, using anonymous inner class and then, call the overridden method, e.g.:

```
class X {
    void methodX() {
        Y y = new Y() {
            @Override
            void doIt(Example x) {
                x.methodExample();
            }
        };
        y.doIt(new Example() {
            public void methodExample() {
                System.out.println("methodExample");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To call this, you can simply do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    X x = new X();
    x.methodX();
}
```